# Get JSON from file

Tags: logstash

*Logstash 5.2.1*

I can't read JSON documents from [a local file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/3.0/snippets/shakespeare.json) using Logstash. There are no documents in the stdout.

I run Logstash like this:

```
./logstash-5.2.1/bin/logstash -f logstash-5.2.1/config/shakespeare.conf --config.reload.automatic
```

Logstash config:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/trex/Development/Shipping_Data_To_ES/shakespeare.json"
    codec => json {}   
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Also, I tried with `charset`:

```
...
codec => json {
  charset => "UTF-8"
}
...
```

Also, I tried with/without `json` codec in the input and with filter:

```
...
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
...
```

Logstash console after start:

```
[2017-02-28T11:37:29,947][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] fetched new config for pipeline. upgrading.. {:pipeline=>"main", :config=>"input {\n  file {\n    path => \"/home/trex/Development/Shipping_Data_To_ES/shakespeare.json\"\n    codec => json {\n      charset => \"UTF-8\"\n    }\n    start_position => \"beginning\"\n  }\n}\n#filter {\n#  json {\n#    source => \"message\"\n#  }\n#}\noutput {\n  stdout {\n    codec => rubydebug\n  }\n}\n\n"}
[2017-02-28T11:37:29,951][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
[2017-02-28T11:37:30,434][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-02-28T11:37:30,446][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
^C[2017-02-28T11:40:55,039][WARN ][logstash.runner          ] SIGINT received. Shutting down the agent.
[2017-02-28T11:40:55,049][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
^C[2017-02-28T11:40:55,475][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] SIGINT received. Terminating immediately..
The signal INT is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform
[trex@Latitude-E5510 Shipping_Data_To_ES]$ ./logstash-5.2.1/bin/logstash -f logstash-5.2.1/config/shakespeare.conf --config.test_and_exit
^C[trex@Latitude-E5510 Shipping_Data_To_ES]$ ./logstash-5.2.1/bin/logstash -f logstash-5.2.1/config/shakespeare.conf --confireload.automatic
^C[trex@Latitude-E5510 Shipping_Data_To_ES]$ ./logstash-5.2.1/bin/logstash -f logstash-5.2.1/config/shakespeare.conf --config.reload.aumatic
Sending Logstash's logs to /home/trex/Development/Shipping_Data_To_ES/logstash-5.2.1/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-02-28T11:45:48,752][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-02-28T11:45:48,785][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-02-28T11:45:48,875][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

Why Logstash doesn't put my JSON documents in stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try including the file [type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.2/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-type) within your `file` input:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/trex/Development/Shipping_Data_To_ES/shakespeare.json"
    type => "json"  <-- add this
    //codec => json {} <-- for the moment i'll comment this  
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
```

And then have your **filter** as such:

```
filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
}
```

**OR** if you're going with the `codec` plugin make sure to have the synopsis as such within your `input`:

```
codec => "json"
```

**OR** you might want to try out [json_lines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json_lines.html#plugins-codecs-json_lines) plugin as well. Hope this [thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/best-way-to-parse-json-input/29809/4) comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [sincedb_path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#_tracking_of_current_position_in_watched_files) is important to read JSON files. I was able to import the JSON only after adding this option. It is needed to maintain the current position in the file to be able to resume from that position in case the import is interrupted. I don't need any position tracking, so I just set this to `/dev/null` and it works.

The basic working Logstash configuration:

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/home/trex/Development/Shipping_Data_To_ES/shakespeare.json"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => json_lines
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "shakespeare" 
  }  
}
```